# Is there a faster way to create a df from a txt file?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, optimization

I have a .txt file with lines such as "G1 X174.774 Y46.362 E1.48236", "M73 Q1 S245", all with one letter then a number and then a space. I'm trying to create a dataframe such that each row is a line from my file and each column is a letter. If my file were just the two lines above, my resulting dataframe would be

```
G X       Y      E       M  Q S
1 174.774 46.362 1.48236 0  0 0
0 0       0      0       73 1 245
```

So far I have a dataframe with the columns of all possible letters in the .txt file, and the .txt file is now represented as a list of strings representing each line of the file. As of now I can only figure out how to add each line individually to the df with the following for loop:

```
for j in tqdm(range(len(lines))):
            line = lines[j]
            points = line.split()
            k = [x[0] for x in points]
            v = [x[1:] for x in points]
            line_dict = dict(zip(k, v))
            df.loc[j] = pd.Series(line_dict)
```

This gives me my desired result (the unspecified values are NaN, but I can change these to zero later), but as my files have 200k+ lines, it's taking about an hour per file. Is there a faster way I could do this? I've been trying to think of a way to use list comprehension, but using the dict is confusing me a bit, and I'm not sure how much faster that would make things anyway. I haven't been able to find much on stackoverflow about this subject, but if I missed something please feel free to share the link with me! Thanks!

Comment: The file you're parsing looks like gcode. Is it? There's likely a fast gcode parser which already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I suspect there is. *Do not incrementally increase the number of rows in a dataframe* in a loop:

```
df.loc[j] = pd.Series(line_dict)
```

This will result in quadratic time complexity.

Instead, accumulate those dicts into a list, then create a pandas dataframe from that list at the very end. So:

```
data = []
for line in tqdm(range(lines)):
    points = line.split()
    k = [x[0] for x in points]
    v = [x[1:] for x in points]
    line_dict = dict(zip(k, v))
    data.append(line_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The above should be linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `sep` parameter in `pandas.read_csv` could be a good idea. If  the separator is space, then the dataframe constructing could be implemented as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')
```

Comment: See what dataframe you get and what you need BEFORE offering a "solution".